# Node-Redis Asynchrounous testing using mocha

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, node-redis

I have a simple asynchronous code written in Node.JS which adds a string to a Redis SET . Here is the code , it is saved in a file called redis_ops.js

```
 var redis = require('redis');
 exports.addUser= function(){
    var client = redis.createClient();
    client.on("error",function(err){
        console.log('Error'+ err);
    });
   client.select(1);
   client.sadd("users","naveen",function(err,reply){
        if(err)
            throw err;
        return reply;

   });
  console.log("at the end of the adduser function")
  }
```

Since the client.sadd is asynchronous , the function containing client.sadd returns before client.sdd finishes . 
Here is the test written using Mocha

```
var assert = require("assert");
var core = require('./redis_ops.js');

describe('COREAPI', function(){
    describe('addUser', function(){
        it('should return 1 if the user is added successfully', function(){
        assert.equal(1,core.addUser() );

    })
  })
})
```

The test fails since the redis_ops returns undefined (no return value) since the function containing client.sadd returns first and the asynchronous client.sadd returns later with the intended value to be asserted in the test . How do i test the return the value from the asynchronous client.sadd without code duplication or without containing all the code in the same file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mocha allows you to test asynchronous functions using an optional callback.

```
describe('COREAPI', function () {
    describe('addUser', function () {
        it('should return 1 if the user is added successfully', function (done) {
            core.addUser(function (err, result) {
                assert.ifError(err);
                assert.equal(result, 1);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Your redis_ops.js file has issues. You *must not* throw in a callback to an asynchronous function. By convention, the callback may only take an error as the first argument (or null if there was no error), and other arguments for results.

The throw in your code will result in uncaught exceptions, even if you try yo catch it, since try-catch only works for synchronous code. You must reformat this to look like:

```
var client = require('redis').createClient();

client.on('error', function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});

exports.addUser = function () {
    client.select(1, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err)
        }

        client.sadd('users', 'naveen', function (err, reply) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }

            console.log('at the end of the adduser function')

            callback(null, reply);
        });
    });
};
```

Or using the `client.multi` batching facility of the redis module, `exports.addUser` might look like:

```
exports.addUser = function () {
    var multi = client.multi();

    multi.select(1).sadd('users', 'naveen').exec(function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        callback(null, results[1]);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you very for helping me understand testing asynchronous code ..Very helpful answer .

Comment: On one hand `core.addUser(function (err, result) {...`, but on the other hand `exports.addUser = function () {...`. Missing a `callback` parameter perhaps? Moreover, `client.on("error", function (err) { callback(err); });` can't work since there is no `callback` in scope.

Comment: @Louis yup that `callback` should have been a `console.error`. The  `core` is correct though, since presumably `core` is the name of the module for which we are appending functions to the exports. i.e. the top listing is in a test module, the lower two are within the `core` module.

Comment: Its working on removing the line "assert.ifError(err)" , but not able to understand why ?

Comment: If it's working when that line is removed then it likely means that the timeout error is coming from the redis client. Try adding a console.log on the client `'connect'` event to see if it's managing to connect to the redis server.